# How to pass parameters into onclick function parameters into dynamically created buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript reads text from a file and creates button dynamically base on the button creation below. The problem I am facing is it is not able to call the function on click. I've tried removing the parameters to call it and it works however I can't seem to get it to work with passing of parameters. Can someone help me with it?

JS:

```
function toggleVisibility(type){
    alert(type);
}
```

Button creation:

```
var button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-inverse active" data-toggle="button tooltip" title="Click this to enable/disable viewing of '+this+'" onclick="toggleVisibility('+"'"+this+"'"+')">'+word+'</button>';
```

Comment: if you want to use onclick attributes, the functions they call must exist on the global scope.

Comment: What exactly is `this` when creating the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use inline handlers, first of all, and it's easier to create it with jQuery anyways:

```
var that = this;
var button = $("<button>");
button.addClass("btn btn-block btn-inverse active");
button.attr({
    type: "button",
    "data-toggle": "button tooltip",
    title: "Click this to enable/disable viewing of " + that
});
button.text(word);
button.on("click", function () {
    toggleVisibility(that);
});
```

(yes, I know you could chain all of the method calls, I just wanted to do it this way)

When you're ready to put this button somewhere, just use `$container.append(button);`.

Everything depends on what `this` is or what you want/expect it to be. If you need the parameter passed to `toggleVisibility` to be the specific button that was just clicked (I'm guessing to toggle its visibility), just pass `this` (ignore the `that`). As for setting the `title` attribute, I'm not sure what you want :)

If you have an HTML structure like:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- Buttons go somewhere in here -->
</div>
```

And you're appending the buttons to that container (or somewhere in that container), it would be more efficient to bind a single `click` handler to the container with event delegation:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".special-btn-identifier", function () {
    toggleVisibility(this);
});
```

Of course, you'd need to add a "special-btn-identifier" class to the buttons, so that this event handler will work (and remove the individual `click` handlers for each button, as this will cover them). This single event handler only needs to run once, preferably as soon as the `#container` is ready...like in `$(document).ready(function () {});`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and help! I'm picking up jQuery and uses it to create this set of buttons. Just did not know I can do this!

Comment: @U.f.O Ahh okay, well glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following line:

```
.. onclick="toggleVisibility('+"'"+this+"'"+')">'+word+'</button>';
```

for this one:

```
.. onclick="toggleVisibility(this)">'+word+'</button>';
```

as you dont need to escape the `this` keyword, nor including a different `this` from the context where you were creating the button text.

Comment: I think they're trying to pass a reference to `this` from where they're creating the button, not the reference to the button. Not sure though, the OP is a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

Register the onClick event on the document instead of in the html when you create the button.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn-inverse', function() { toggleVisibility(this); return false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create inline HTML strings, don't use intrusive Javascript.

Though I don't even advise you to create them with vanilla jQuery, you may try with:

```
var $button = $('<button></button>', {
  'text'        : word
  'type'        : 'button',
  'class'       : 'btn btn-block btn-inverse active',
  'data-toggle' : 'button tooltip',
  ...
  // any other attributes
});

// append the $button anywere

$( someContainer ).append($button);

$( someContainer ).on('click', '.btn', function(event){

  // you can refer to the button with $(this) here

});
```